# mean value /integral

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I consider the probability space $(\Omega, F,P) $

How can I verify, that the follwing holds:

$$ \int_G X dP = E[1_G X] \ for \ G \in F$$

Comment: If $E[f(X)] = \int_{\Omega}f(\omega) X(\omega) dP(\omega)$ then you can see it directly substituting for $f = 1_G$

Comment: by definition..

Comment: In most books you will see it just as a definition of a Lebesgue integral over a subset.

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments : Since $G\in \mathcal F$, therefore $G\subseteq \Omega$, so the integral over $G$ is exactly the integral over $\Omega$ where the measurable event $G$ is indicated.

$$\int_G X\mathrm d\mathsf P = \int_\Omega \mathbf 1_G\, X\,\mathrm d\mathsf P$$

Which, by definition of expectation, is $\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_G X)$.

$$\int_G X\mathrm d\mathsf P=\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_G X)$$

That is all.